# Insert Row in between query result or using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have a set of data here, example below

[image]

and I am trying to get a result similar to this

[image]

I am thinking of using query, and I found this query formula:

```
=query({Sheet1!$A$1:$A;Sheet1!$B$1:$B;Sheet1!$C$1:$C},"select * where Col1 <>'' ",0)
```

but this only applies in transforming wide to long dataset

Is there a way to do it using query? or even an app script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to add a set of values with only the first two words. For that you can use:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(UNIQUE(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"(.+ .+) "))&"¿¿"),"¿",1,0))
```

[image]

PS: the two ¿¿ are for adding the extra columns. If you actually have more columns, add more ¿ signs -- (you don't need to do this step, I'm just showing you the process)

Then, with the query:

```
=QUERY({A:C;INDEX(SPLIT(UNIQUE(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"(.+ .+) "))&"¿¿"),"¿",1,0))},"Select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1")
```

You'll get something like this in the right:

[image]

Then, with conditional formatting you can get something like this:

```
=($I1<>"")*($J1="")*($K1="")
```

PS: adapt the actual columns

[image]

Comment: This works well with my dataset, another question, how can I make it case insensitive?

Comment: You can change here PROPER with UPPER or LOWER depending on the output you desire: `=QUERY({A:C;INDEX(SPLIT(UNIQUE(IFERROR(PROPER(REGEXEXTRACT(A:A,"(.+ .+) ")))&"¿¿"),"¿",1,0))},"Select * where Col1 is not null order by Col1")`